# How to explain results from a graph of a variable transformed with exponential function?

Tags: data-visualization, data-transformation, back-transformation

I had to transform my response variable before my analysis, but the only transformation that worked well was the exponential. So, I could not back-transform my values to the original scale. How do I interpret/explain the graph in my results if values are different from the original scale?

thanks a lot for your suggestions

[image]

Comment: Why can you not take a log?

Comment: The distribution of the residuals was not normal. The values are positive, negative and also zeros. I will post a picture of the residuals on my question. Thank you @dsaxton

Comment: I meant take a log of something on an exponential scale.  This would be the way to transform it back.

Comment: now my graph looks different, I assume this is the real effect, not the one shown by the transformed variable on the axis, right? thanks!